# How can I compute the result of the intensity of edges given by the compass operator of an image?

Tags: convolution, image-processing

I have an image with 11x11 pixels and in the center of the image is a square of 5x5 pixels, with the gray level of the background 0 and the gray level of the square is 50. How can I compute the result of the magnitude of edges(intensity of the contour) given by the compass operator for this image taking into account that the image is not noisy?
I know that the Sobel operator only considers the two orientations which are 0 and 90 degrees convolution
masks as here, but I don't know how to apply the math on paper...

[image]

These kernels can then be combined together to find the absolute magnitude of the gradient at each point. The gradient magnitude is given by:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to perform the convolution?

Comment: @Zim I'm asking how can I apply the math here in order to solve the problem

Comment: https://i.imgflip.com/3xg04f.jpg

Comment: @Zim so my algorithm its correct, no?

Comment: @Zim are u still here?